# Xamarin.iOS and Crashlytics binding api compile error

Tags: ios, xamarin, crashlytics

We are trying to use Crashlytics api in a `Xamarin.iOS` environment. 
We have made a binding project on the static library provided by Crashlytics.
When we use it in a little test project, it works perfectly.

But, when we use it with our real project, in the same way, the native compiler fails, with the following errors :

```
duplicate symbol _CLSClientAdvertisingIdKey in:\
    /Users/dave/Documents/TFS/MXT0/MAIN-IPAD-1.2-IOS7/xxx.Mono/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/Crashlytics.a(CLSClient.o)\
    /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libcrashreporting.a(CLSClient.o)\

duplicate symbol _CLSClientDeviceIdKey in:\
    /Users/dave/Documents/TFS/MXT0/MAIN-IPAD-1.2-IOS7/xxx.Mono/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/Crashlytics.a(CLSClient.o)\
    /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libcrashreporting.a(CLSClient.o)\
    ...
    ...
```

...101 more errors with same .a conflict but on different symbols

We are using :

- Xamarin Studio 4.2.1 (build 1)
- Xamarin.iOS 7.0.4.209
- Mono 3.2.4
- Xcode 4.6.3

We are using some third party api binding too (picked from Xamarin component store):

- iRate Rating Prompt (1.8.0)
- Facebook iOS SDK (3.0.9)
- ZipArchive

Any idea on what is referencing the static library “libcrashreporting.a“ and link it with our build ?
Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Here is the complete build log http://pastebin.com/MEeiwrBx

Comment: Could you pastebin your entire build output?

Comment: Just curious where you got libcrashreporting.a?  The binary in the supplied Crashlytics.framework is named "Crashlytics".

Comment: @Erik : I have rename "Crashlytics" to "Crashlytics.a" and use it in my binding project. The libcrashreporting library can be found in Xamarin.iOS framework.

Comment: @Rolf I just have added a link to the complete build log at the end of my question.

Comment: @Harween: you have enabled Crashlytics support for the project, so you do not need to link with Crashlytics.a yourself, this is done automatically by Xamarin.iOS. Also you might want to edit the pastebin, since your Crashlytics API key is visible.

Comment: Thank you for the key, it was a test account.

Comment: @Rolf : I'm confused. Do you mean that I can forget the call of  Crashlytics.StartWithAPIKey("myKey") in the FinishedLaunching method of AppDelegate class ? A Xamarin studio build phase will do this for me ? Can you explain how it is working ? Why my little test project doesn't reveal the same issue ?

Comment: You do not need to call StartWithAPIKey if you're using the Crashlytics support that comes with Xamarin.iOS, this is done automatically by Xamarin.iOS at startup. Your test project did probably not reveal the same issue because you didn't enable Xamarin.iOS' Crashlytics support.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for your support. And have a good week-end :)